# Extjs: Dynamically add item to cycle button

Tags: extjs4

Using extjs I am creating a Cycle Button. At time of generation I am adding three menu items to this cycle button, following is a code for this,

`Ext.create('Ext.button.Cycle', {
                id: 'trneMapCycleBtn',
                showText: true,
                flex: 2,
                tooltip: "Click here to change boundary",
                prependText: '',
                menu: {
                      id: 'view-type-menu',
                    items: [{
                        text: 'Districts',
                        checked: true,
                        tootip: "Delhi Districts boundary",
                        type: "getDistricts"
                    }, {
                        text: 'State',
                        tootip: "Delhi State boundary",
                        type: "getStates"
                    },{
                        text: 'Circles',
                        tootip: "Delhi Circles boundary",
                        type: "getCircles"
                    }]
                },`

After its creation, I am later accessing this cycle button using its id and trying to add a menu items into this,

`function createItemForGeoJason(){

             var menuItem = new Ext.menu.CheckItem({
                            text : geoJsonLayerName,
                            id: 'geoJsonItem',
                            handler: function(menuItem){
                                     var layer =     map.getLayersByName(myTrendMapSelectedLayer);
                                     layer[0].setVisibility(false);
                                     var layer1 =    map.getLayersByName(geoJsonLayerName);
                                     layer1[0].setVisibility(true);
                                    }
                                 });

                Ext.getCmp('view-type-menu').add(menuItem);
          }`

Answer (score 0):

You must overwrite adding menu item, because Button class doesn't have add function. Try this:

```
Ext.getCmp('view-type-menu').menu.add(menuItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
testButton.menu.add({
    xtype: "menucheckitem",
    text: "some text",
    group: testButton.id,                  // important!
    checkHandler: testButton.checkHandler, // important!
    scope: xBtnChartCase                   // important!
});
```

instead of:

```
testButton.menu.add(new Ext.menu.CheckItem({...}));
```